# Is vortex physics key to understand the universe simulation hypothesis?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, universe, quantum-computer, bose-einstein-condensate, vortex

Seth Lloyd, US computer scientist and Professor of Mechanical Engineering and Physics at the renowned Massachusetts Institute of Technology (MIT) says that the universe itself is a giant quantum computer, calculating itself and its own evolution.

The following short interview (2 min 14 sec) was recorded back in November 2010 at the Institute for Quantum Computing, University of Waterloo.

**Seth Lloyd on the Universe as a Quantum Computer**

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qh8QfKVcvFA

*“In fact, when we are building Quantum computers, it is not like we are starting from scratch and saying, “Oh we have these dumb Qubits and they are not computing, they can’t do anything, let us make them compute”…ähm…that is not the way it works, it is more that the universe itself is already processing information at this microscopic level all the time and when we build a quantum computer we are just coming in and highjacking the ongoing computation to make it compute something that we would like it to compute rather than what it would normally be computing.
So yes, I mean if you would like to think of yourself when you are building a quantum computer is simply participating in a larger computation in a productive way, I think that is a nicer way to think than to saying "We are going to force the universe to compute at the microscopic level." So, we are participating in the universal computation rather than forcing the universe to compute."*

An argument for this hypothesis could be the superfluid time crystal structure (hexagonal Abrikosov vortex lattice) shown below, which could serve as the underlying naturally generated quantum mechanical transition matrix (hardware).

**Abrikosov Vortex Lattice [Entangled, Holographic, Naturally Occurring]**
[image]
Source: https://jila.colorado.edu/bec/CornellGroup/gallery/images/vortexnuc_color.jpg

It is important to note that the quantum mechanical nature of a BEC-superfluid can lead to very unusual phenomena. A particularly striking consequence is that a BEC-superfluid cannot rotate like a classical liquid. Instead, when a BEC-superfluid is set into rapid rotation, vortices enter the condensate and arrange themselves into a regular lattice (Abrikosov vortex lattice).

**Question:**
Is the universe a quantum computer and the hexagonal Abrikosov vortex lattice the underlying naturally generated quantum mechanical transition matrix?

*Note: This question is not a duplicate to the pure philosophical or the mathematical model based universe simulation hypothesis as it adds a novel aspect with the recently discovered superfluid hexagonal Abrikosov vortex lattice for which convincing experimental evidence can be found on the US National Science Foundation Website.
https://www.nsf.gov/news/mmg/mmg_disp.jsp?med_id=59577&from=

Comment: I think this is philosophy and metaphysics, another way of stating one's beliefs. A higher level to the platonic ideals.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/484446/2451 and links therein.

Comment: This question is neither a duplicate nor related to philosophy or metaphysics, but deals mainly with the recently discovered hexagonal Abrikosov vortex lattice and its possible implications (based on experimental evidence provided by researchers in the group of Professor Eric Cornell who have succeeded in nucleating up to 300 vortices in an individual Bose-Einstein condensate and studied their dynamics). Here the Link to the US National Science Foundation Website…
https://www.nsf.gov/news/mmg/mmg_disp.jsp?med_id=59577&from=

Comment: The hexagonal, holographic and entangled Abrikosov vortex lattice as potential underlying naturally generated quantum mechanical matrix deserves a more serious and in depth discussion by experts experienced in vortex physics and reopening of this question is kindly requested as the reasons for closing the question are too hasty and not applicable.

Comment: Any thoughts on how continuous rotational symmetry would emerge from an underlying hexagonal lattice?

Comment: Dear Mitchell, I would argue the other way around, the underlying hexagonal arrangement of the Abrikosov vortex lattice is clearly visible and might be an inevitable geometrical consequence of the vortices, densest sphere packing. With kind regards