# Can a quantum field theory be completely simulated by a quantum computer?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, simulations, quantum-computer

I heard a talk on quantum computing and black hole. In this talk Leonard susskind raised a question: can QFT be completely simulated by using a quantum computer? But he said he was not going to answer that in this seminar. Is it possible to simulate QFT? What would happen if quantum computer seems to do it?

Comment: QFT of what? Link to talk?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/484446/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, it's expectable that quantum computer which operates on quantum laws is naturally suitable for quantum world simulation. It's similar like an universal Turing machine can simulate itself (or other Turing machines), and so "Universal quantum machine" should be able to simulate other quantum machinery as well. Albeit I can't prove it.