Can a universe-sized computer predict the universe?
I'm not asking about a simulation and so I don't see this as a duplicate, and I'm not a physicist or anything like that, I have some physics-related questions though.
Current models suggest local space is flat. It has been suggested by various authors that the universe is "infinite" in size.
Hypothetically, let's suppose in the future that technology advances, and we determine with razor-sharp precision that the space of the universe has a very small local curvature, and so the universe is actually spherical or torus shaped, suggesting one can return to their starting position by traveling in a straight line, and that there are only a finite number atoms in the universe at a given time. Even this idea might not be consistent with the standard model still, since "knowing" the exact number of atoms in the universe requires measuring each of them to confirm their existence.
Now, I'm not assuming the universe is finite, I'm just supposing it is finite for the purposes of asking this question.
Some physicists I've met are arrogant just because they can predict the exact future state of a single, isolated fermion given 26 fundamental numbers.
However, this is much, much more difficult when you have trillions of fermions. This easily gives rise to chaos (though still potentially deterministic) governed by non-linear partial differential equations which are intrinsically limited in predictability.
However, before dismissing the idea that the future state of the universe is unpredictable, let's consider the additional possibility that space and time may be quantized, and that ideas governing partial differential equations (limits to infinity) are not physically realized, that space time is not "infinitely" indivisible and thus that there are constraints in the capacity of the theory of partial differential equations to accurately model reality on a sufficiently small scale.
In this instance of both a bounded universe, and, a quantized universe, is it possible to borrow ideas from both physics and computer science to prove that a sufficiently large computer, like a universe-sized computer, could predict the exact future state of all fermions from a single frame of reference, given sufficient initial data?
Or, are there even more complexities that would inhibit this?

Hmm, you're right, although it is a technical nuance to get comfortable with. The shortest distance between two points in space-time is curved by current models, so by those models you must be right that spacetime is curved, so I'll correct that.

Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/484446/2451 and links therein.

I wasn't quite fast enough to get my answer in before the question was closed. I posted it on the duplicate question.

Sorry, but this isn't a duplicate. I'm not asking to simulate the universe, I'm asking whether the effort it takes to predict all future states can be physically realized. This is separate from simulating a universe, in which case it would give rise to conscious entities like us. In my question, I'm only interested in the numbers, I'm not interested in "recreating" the universe.

Does the universe-sized computer fill the universe that it is trying to predict ? In other words, are you asking "can a computer predict its own future state" ?

@gandalf61 That's an interesting conundrum I was thinking about, but I am not assuming so. In other words, is there an actual, predictable measure of how hard it is to predict the exact future state of all fermions in the universe, if the universe is bounded and all space and all time is quantized? Such predictions could be made by a theoretical, "outside" computer in a parallel universe.

You said, "This is separate from simulating a universe," But, suppose some colossal machine could predict the evolution of our universe with perfect accuracy. How would that not be a "simulation?"

@SolomonSlow That's very easy for me to answer. It's because this machine spits out numbers and distributions, you plug in initial values for various equations, and it spits out a series of numbers and distributions, it does not run a time-dependent scenario and admits no physics engine, nor contextualization As far as the computer knows, "physics" doesn't exist.

How the machine describes some future state of the universe is irrelevant. It's what the machine does to compute that future state is what's important. You yourself said that the behavior of "trillions of fermions" would be chaotic. I don't know how you can predict the outcome of chaos except by faithfully simulating the process. That's what I'm asking. And BTW, "trillions of fermions" isn't a universe. It's barely even a dust speck. How are you going to compute a future state of $10^{80}$ or more particles except by running the simulation?

@SolomonSlow Chaos and determinism are not mutually exclusive, even though it seems random. Consider the digits of pi. The digits of pai seem chaotic, in the sense you'll never be able to predict the last number, but, that doesn't mean the digits are random either, And, even though a computer cannot add infinitely many numbers together, if the universe is quantized, such a computer may not need to.

I never said that you can't predict the future of a chaotic system. I asked how you were going to do it without faithfully simulating the system. The first sentence of your original question says, "I'm not asking about a simulation." So I'm asking back, "if not a simulation, then what?" What kind of a machine could predict some future state of the universe without predicting its evolution over the whole interval from some given initial conditions to the final, predicted state?

A 1980's handheld calculator can give you the volume of a sphere. Is that calculator running a simulation just because it gives you the volume of what we think of as a 3D sphere?
